# Input field doubleclick and focus() bug - Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, google-chrome

Okey! I have tried to find an answer in StackOverflow (SC) to this mysterious behaviour on GH (version - 48) which I think came out at the beginning of this month but I just couldn't find a similar post describing the problem or even something close to it.

This JS Fiddle should be self-explanatory: https://jsfiddle.net/xbu061yw/4/

The HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  <input type="input" disabled>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <input type="input" disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

The JS & jQuery:

```
$('.box').dblclick( function() {

    $(this).find("input").prop("disabled", false).focus();

});

$('.box').focusout(function() {

    $(this).find("input").prop("disabled", true);

});
```

(If you will open the fiddle in Safari or an older GH version then there will be no bug).

---

Description of the behaviour:

On page load the inputs are disabled. (Doesn't matter if the inputs are disabled through inline attributes in HTML or through JS on page load). The double-click event in JS removes the "disabled" attribute and sets focus to the input element. **Here comes the fun part: Try to type something with the ceret focused in the input field!** Nothing happens!

Even more fun begins when you put a focusout event handler on the input field to set the attribute "disabled" to true. When the input field is disabled for the second time, if you try to enter it with the double-click again you can't see the caret blinking (even though the input field has focus) but you can type in now and everything seems to be fine again.

If you continue and to the "last step of the circle" which is - delete everything you just entered in the input field and click outside of it so that you trigger the focusout event. If you do this then everything starts from the beginning as you double-click on the input field.

---

I hope I described the problem in an understandable fashion!

So my questions would be:

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is there a solution to this problem?

Cheers!

---

**Update:**

Looks like the bug can be reproduced only on OS X! The Fiddle works fine on Windows GH (version 48).

Comment: Kindly read [ask]. Putting `====` is like annoying. `:)`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar thanks! I was in a hurry!

Comment: No worries, I have corrected it.

Comment: I have Chrome 48 on Win 8.1 and your fiddle is working fine for me.

Comment: @MatiK Thanks for the response! Then looks like it's also a mac specific bug for Chrome! Will edit the question and put an extra tag.